# How to receive simple text using InputStream in a Thread? Android

Tags: android, sockets, inputstream

I am running a server which writes a simple Welcome message to a new Client upon Successful connection!
Now I am sure of it that my android device connects to the server but I am unable to receive the welcome text that the server sends.
I am new to socket programming and I am looking for a unified solution to this.
I will paste my code which has a successful outputStream snippet and gets the android connected to the server. I ll leave the InputStream section black, since I need the solution for that!

```
private ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> mQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(100);
private AtomicBoolean mStop = new AtomicBoolean(false);

private OutputStream mOutputStream = null;
private InputStream mInputStream = null;

private Socket mSocket = null;

private static Thread sNetworkThread = null;
private final Runnable mNetworkRunnable = new Runnable() {

        log("starting network thread");
        String encoding = "UTF-8";
        String output="";

    @Override
    public void run() {
        log("starting network thread");

        try {
            mSocket = new Socket(ARDUINO_IP_ADDRESS, PORT);
            mOutputStream = mSocket.getOutputStream();
            mInputStream = mSocket.getInputStream();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            mStop.set(true);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            mStop.set(true);
        }

        mQueue.clear(); // we only want new values

        //Output Stream
        try {
            while(!mStop.get()){
                int val = mQueue.take();
                if(val >= 0){
                    log("sending value "+val);
                    mOutputStream.write((val+"\n").getBytes());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            try {
                mStop.set(true);
                if(mOutputStream != null) mOutputStream.close();
                if(mSocket != null) mSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //InputStream
         try 
         {
            //Call method to read inputStream
            output = readFully(mInputStream,encoding);

         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Server Message"+output, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        log("returning from network thread");
        sNetworkThread = null;
    }
};
```

Well I added two methods to achieve the inputStream by calling it from the thread. The methods are as follows.

```
 public String readFully(InputStream inputStream, String encoding)
            throws IOException {
        return new String(readFully(inputStream), encoding);
    }

    private byte[] readFully(InputStream inputStream)
            throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

** The Server returns a String - "Welcome New User"
Well I hv used putty in RAW mode to coonect to the server and it works fine.

StackTrace Logs:

```
03-02 16:46:22.790  11813-12339/com.example.bonny.myapplication D/>==< ArduinoYun >==<﹕ starting network thread
03-02 16:46:22.790  11813-12339/com.example.bonny.myapplication D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo  hn 9, servname NULL, ai_family 0+
03-02 16:46:22.790  11813-12339/com.example.bonny.myapplication D/libc﹕ [NET] ht 0x31302e302e302e
03-02 16:46:22.790  11813-12339/com.example.bonny.myapplication D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo-exit SUCCESS
```

I need to integrate the inputStream on this thread.

P.S. OutputStream works smoothly from this code!

Comment: Well show the read()'s you tried. What was the problem? Tell what the server sends exactly.

Comment: If you're asking ho to receive you have to show the code that does it. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: Can be. But you should of course tell what happens now. What does readFully() return? What do you see in that Toast()? Tell the flow. Tell what's happening. And comment on Amrut Bidri's code please. That's how it goes here.

Comment: @greenapps the "readFully()" method returns the 'byte-converted-to-string' format from the inputStream.
Well the toasts never pops up.

and yes thanks for the advice.I have replied to him.

Comment: `'byte-converted-to-string' format from the inputStream ` I did not ask for that. If `The Server returns a String - "Welcome New User" ` then i want to know what the client receives. Everybody wants to know that. `Surely this is obvious?` ;-).

Comment: You cannot place a Toast() in void run(). It will crash your app. Remove it. Let the following log() print `output`. And tell us what it prints..

Comment: @greenapps It only shows the Succeccful connection to the server.
but never shows a stacktrace on inputbuffer.
Its totally empty.
It seems it never receives the input.
Could you check if the implementation of the code to intercept the inputStream is correct? I mean..if I am calling the methods from the right place ,in the thread!

Comment: `It only shows the Succeccful connection`. Where is that in your code? I see no log() statement for that. Please add much more log() statements in your client code so you can see which statements are executed and where it stops. Add some basic debug statements i would say. You can do that after every code line. Find out how the flow goes.

Comment: Your client is first sending something to the server and then reading. Does the server expect this behaviour?

Comment: hmm...good point!
Well on successful connection. The server firsts sends the welcome message and then expects to receive messages from client.
and client will send the message only when the atomic boolean 'mStop' is true. (Its hooked up to a seekbar)
Anyway It seems it never reaches inside the try/catch block of the inpurstream.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read *one line.* Your present code tries to read everything until end of stream, whuch only happens when the peer closes the connection.

Comment: Ok. It makes sense on what you just said!
Well I am kinda lost here. Trying every step I can!
Could you jus write a small snippet as an example on how I can intercept the inputStream till it hits a carriage return "\n"?

The incoming String from server is "Welcome New Client\n"

It would be of great help.

Comment: That @Amrut Bidri told you already in `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
public String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is)
{

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try
    {

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (br != null)
        {
            try
            {
                br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Above code might help you in converting InputStream into String.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: This will read or block until the peer closes the connection. He only wants to read one response.

Comment: @Amrut Bidri
Yes, its a good method but I also kinda have the same implementation on my methods. 
I think the problem is on how I am calling the methods inside the Thread!
The stacktraces are empty...returns nothing on the logcat.
I think your method is correct but it seems it never makes it till the methods.
its jus blank